# FFI Primitive Type Size

Tags: rust, ffi, primitive-types

Assume, I have a C/C++ Header with a type definition like this:

```
typedef int WORD;
```

And a function like this:

```
WORD test(WORD input);
```

Now, as I understand it, a int in C/C++ can be of a different size, depending on the platform.
If I now link Rust Code to a dll with said function, can my FFI break because of a different sized primitive type?
How can I guard against that?

Comment: "can my FFI break because of a different sized primitive type?" yes "How can I guard against that? " not really, however because all people make assumption that int == 32 bits it's unlikely to broke still nothing prevent int to be 42 bits. Also, libc crate give an useful abstraction that protect a little versus this kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

`int` in C is guaranteed to have at least size of 2 bytes. Exact size is implementation defined.

C ABI is generally stable across one operating system and architecture.

Rust doesn't have integer types that can vary by size between different architectures (except `isize` and `usize`). It's choice by design, but you can try to use variable sized types that are guaranteed to correspond with target system C ABI.

```
use libc::c_int;
```

C types from [libc](https://crates.io/libc) crate are exactly what you need.

But I will recommend to not rely on types that can have variable size and instead use fixed width integer types like [int32_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) in C and `i32` in Rust. Coding correctly with different sizes of primitive types in mind can be sometimes challenging.

**EDIT**: By byte I mean byte which has exactly 8 bits, not byte defined by C standard.

Comment: No need to use libc if all you need are the primitive types. The standard library has them all defined in [`std::os::raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/raw/index.html).